# Airlines with the most Surfboard friendly baggage policy & fees pricing?

Tags: luggage, airlines, price, fees-and-charges, surfing

Which airlines have the best pricing or packages for moving or carrying surf boards?

Comment: Is this in a general sense of "anywhere in the world"? Or are you planning to fly from/to somewhere in particular with your board?

Comment: @Gagravarr - Airline policies & experiences of people as mentioned in the linked article below in Toms answer. I will be planning a trip based on how the airlines treat surfboards.

Comment: And who/ why gave this question a -2 negative? It would be so helpful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G.I.Y.F.......................

http://wavetribecompany.com/2014-airline-surfboard-boardbag-fee-guide-for-surfers/